# Multiple documents open at the same time, each with different menu item states

Tags: cocoa, macos, menu, menuitem, nsdocument

In a Cocoa document-based application, what's the best way to keep the menu item states in the menu bar in sync with the currently visible document?

For example, say you have a document with a ruler view that can be hidden/shown via "Show Rulers" (off state) and "Hide Rulers" (on state) menu items.  The user has two documents open at the same time.  He/she has hidden the rulers in one document, but not on the other.  When the user moves between the documents the menu item should reflect the state for that document, not for the application as a whole.

How does one do this cleanly?  I've googled around but it doesn't seem like there's a predefined "out of the box" way to do this.  It would be nice if NSDocument had some sort of "didRegainFocus" type method where such logic can be added.

My actual implementation is a bit trickier since it's actually a NSViewController inside my NSDocument that deals with these particular menu items.

```
@interface MyDocument : NSDocument {
  SomeViewController *myCustomizedTextViewController;
}
```

When `MyDocument` is the currently active document, I need methods in `myCustomizedTextViewController` to ensure the state of a couple of `NSMenuItem`s in the application's main menu.  One is genuinely a ruler.  The other is a similar temporary setting.

Comment: Thanks for that question, I was wondering the exact same thing when starting my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the target of the menu items implement the `validateUserInterfaceItem:` method to enable/disable them. See the [User Interface Validation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/UIValidation.html) reference for more info.

Comment: So simple, thank you! I was totally overthinking it and thinking about NSWindowDelegate methods and other over-the-top solutions.  I'd read past the NSUserInterfaceItemValidations documentation and totally missed the intention.  It's working like a dream now, cheers :)